# omitting tuples based on conditions in other tuples

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in my database containing records of friendships.  There are two columns in the table: user1_id, and user2_id, indicating that user1 is friends with user2. It is set up so user1_id is always < user2_id. I'm trying to write a query to return pairs of users sorted by number of mutual friends.  However, I wish to only include pairs that are not friends themselves in the results.  Here's my query so far:

```
SELECT af.1, bf.1, count(*) as count
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM friends
      UNION
      SELECT user2_id, user1_id
      FROM friends ) af,
     (SELECT *
      FROM friends
      UNION
      SELECT user2_id, user1_id
      FROM friends ) bf
WHERE af.1 != bf.1 
AND af.2 = bf.2
GROUP BY af.1, bf.1
ORDER BY count desc
```

This should give me all combination of users sorted by those with the most mutual friends. However, it does not omit tuples containing pairs that are actually friends themselves.  I can do it in java, but I would prefer to do it on the database side.  Is there any good way to do this?

Comment: Which DBMS? (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL?) If it's a decent one, you can use `MINUS`.

Comment: Oracle, but I don't see how a set difference would help me here. I am trying to first find who has the most mutual friends, and then omit the tuples that are already friends with each other.

Comment: Hmm. Yeah, I guess the presence of the `COUNT(*)` field makes it hard to use `MINUS`. If you were *only* selecting `af.1, bf.1`, it would be trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT af.1, bf.1, count(*) as count
FROM (SELECT *
      FROM friends
      UNION
      SELECT user2_id, user1_id
      FROM friends ) af,
     (SELECT *
      FROM friends
      UNION
      SELECT user2_id, user1_id
      FROM friends ) bf
WHERE af.1 != bf.1 
AND af.2 = bf.2
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM friends
                WHERE user1_id = af.1 AND user2_id = bf.1
                OR user1_id = bf.1 AND user2_id = af.1)
GROUP BY af.1, bf.1
ORDER BY count desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to consider using the [CONNECT BY clause](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/to_URL?remark=ranked&urlname=http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries003.htm#i2060615), although that may be overkill.